# Create a file and upload using PhoneGap on Windows Phone

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm using Phonegap on Windows Phone and I need to create a file which can then be uploaded to the server (I would normally POST the data but the server I'm using has a limit on the size of a POST request for some obscure reason). Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is possible using a combination of the W3C file API ([available in Cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html)) and the Cordova [File Transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer).

**1) Install the [File Transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)**

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer

**2) Use code similar to the following**

I'd be tempted to use something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) though to make this more readable.

Note: this code assumes the file is uploaded as an attachment called "file" (you'll need to look out for that on the server).

```
// 1) Request access to the file system
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){

    // 2) Create a new file
    fileSystem.root.getFile("file.json", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry){

        console.log("We now have access to the file: " + fileEntry.fullPath + " -- " + fileEntry.toURL());

        // 3) Create a file write object
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer){

            // 4) Write the information to the file
            writer.write("File contents go here");
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {

                // 5) We've written the data to the file. Now upload.
                var url = "http://serverurl.com";
                var fileURL = fileEntry.toURL();    // Local file URL

                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey = "file";
                options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                options.mimeType = "text/plain";

                // Add any headers, if necessary
                var headers = {
                        "HEADER": "value"
                };
                options.headers = headers;

                console.log("Uploading file at: " + fileEntry.fullPath + " to " + fileURL);
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI(url), function(r){

                    // Upload was successful. You can now do something with the response
                    // This code assumes the response is in JSON format.
                    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
                    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
                    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);

                    var response = JSON.parse(r.response);
                    alert(response.success);

                }, 
                function(error){
                    // An error occurred when attempting to upload. Refer to the following page for an
                    // explanation of the error codes: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer
                    console.log("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                    console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("upload error target " + error.target);

                    alert("Unable to upload file");
                }, options);

            };

        }, function(error){
            console.log("Unable to create file writer: " + error);  
        });

    }, function(error){
        console.log("Unable to create file: " + error);
    });
}, function(error){
    console.log("Unable to access file system: " + error);
});
```